# react router trailing slash not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I am using React 0.14.0, React Router 2.0.0-rc4, browserify 11.2.0, babelify 7.2.0.

Here is my router code:

```
render((
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Departments} />
    <Route path="goals" component={Goals} />
    <Route path="departments" component={Departments} >
      <Route path="department" component={Department} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
), document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

root/departments works fine but not root/departments/. root/departments/department doesn't work neither. I am not sure why.

Also it seems like any kind of parameter with :myParam is not recognized.

I can't see any difference between my code and the examples provided in the documentation.

Another strange thing is that I don't have the warning:

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "undefined" did not match any routes
```

I have:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <        bundle.js:2
```

And if I click on the bundle.js link in the dev tools of chrome I arrive in the index.html (but bundle.js is the name of the tab).

The basic routes such as /, departements and goals work fine.

I am kind of stuck on this. Any advice would be helpful.

Full code available here: https://github.com/codeforabq/Open-Budget-ABQ/tree/dev
Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with a small version of the problem?

Comment: I took a look at your code and launched a server, and the problem isn't in react (yet).  It's in your routing rules in server.js and/or your urls.  You are getting the syntax error because it's trying to lookup bundle.js in /dist/department, which doesn't exist.  I'm playing with a few things, and I'll comment when I get it to work.

Comment: Your asset URLs in index.html need to be absolute.  In index.html, add a slash to the beginning of all your link href's, and to your script src's.

Comment: It fixed some of my problems. I still have errors relevant to the same subject so I am going to update my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'root/departments/department' won't work.

Reason behind this is- department is not a child of 'departments'. It is the child of only 'App' component.

If you want to allow 'root/departments/department' to produce result,then you have to make 'department' as a child of 'departments.

For that you have to give path as described below:

```js
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Departments}>
    <IndexRoute component={Goals} />
      <Route path="department" component={Department} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: I did one minor mistake. Just give Departments path as '/departments' instead of '/'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kris Hardy for your help about the absolute links. That was the solution to my problem.

After prefixing the URL with a / for absolute. I ended up with:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M2.4492935982947065e-15,-40A40,40 0 1,1 NaN,NaNL0,0Z"
```

for http://localhost:3000/departments/ and http://localhost:3000/departments/department

Not very helpful.

I tried the php server (php -S localhost:3000) and I got:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/departments/app/data/budget-first-test.tsv 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught #<XMLHttpRequest>
```

So in app.jsx I fix this line:

```
var dataPath = 'app/data/budget-first-test.tsv';
```

to:

```
var dataPath = '/app/data/budget-first-test.tsv';
```

Now it works perfectly! The parameters work now as well.

Thanks a lot!